# Cheap durable USB hub with type c

Tags: usb, hub

I have a great desktop with one big flaw, very few USB ports and one type c port. I just need a hub that lets me access this type c from a more easy to reach location and also want more USB 3 ports. I've been searching online and I've either found $60+ or very cheap looking hubs. Any help?

Comment: If you are just going for easy to reach, would you consider an extension cable?

Comment: I need 4 more USB ports too! I was hoping a hub would help with keeping it need and not have dangling cables.

Comment: Do you just want 3.x ports are are you wanting it to give you type c ports as well.